# Does dot cloud support http long polling

Tags: xmlhttprequest, websocket, long-polling, dotcloud

I read that dot cloud supports WebSockets. I am planning to use socket.io in my application. Since socket.io will fall back on long polling if browser does not support websockets, I was wondering whether dot cloud supports http long polling.

PS: I am assuming this will depend on hipache which dot cloud uses now as their HTTP load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely something you should test. It is possible that long polling could work, if there is a heartbeat being transmitted more frequently than once per 30 seconds.

I couldn't find a test of socketio longpolling. If you find one in the kit or create one, please link it here.

dotCloud runs Hipache in the default configuration, as published on [github](https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache). In that configuration, the [tcpTimeout](https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache/blob/master/config/config.json#L8) is set to 30 seconds, and any socket which does not send or receive data within that window will be closed by Hipache.

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. I will try with a keepalive of less than 30 seconds.